# Qt Index property is returning negative number

Tags: c++, qt

I'm at a loss. I have a class object where I'm setting a property to an int value. However when i look at the value or try to retrieve it through code it returns a huge negative number. Why is this happening?

[image]

I'm then setting the actual value based on the index of a string position in a list like so:

```
-1163005939
```

**MyObject.h**

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    MyObject(const QString &title, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString title;
    QString getTitle() const;
    void setTitle(const QString &value);

    int index;
    int getIndex() const;
    void setIndex(const int &value);

signals:

public slots:

private:
};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

**MyObject.cpp**

```
#include "myobject.h"

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

MyObject::MyObject(const QString &title, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    setTitle(title);
}

QString MyObject::getTitle() const
{
    return title;
}

void MyObject::setTitle(const QString &value)
{
    title = value;
}

int MyObject::getIndex() const
{
    return index;
}

void MyObject::setIndex(const int &value)
{
    index = value;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QList>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Create a list of objects
    const QStringList names{"Kevin","Amy","Michelle","John"};

    QList<MyObject> objects;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(names[i]);
        // MyObject obj(names[i]);
        obj.setIndex(i);
    }

    // Sort Alphabetically
    std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](const MyObject& a, const MyObject& b) -> bool { return a.getTitle() < b.getTitle(); });
    // Then Sort By Index
    std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(), [](const MyObject& a, const MyObject& b) -> bool { return a.getIndex() < b.getIndex(); });

    // Print info
    for (int i=0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        qDebug() << objects[i].getIndex();
        qDebug() << objects[i].getTitle();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you do not modify your objects in the container, but some temporary objects instead. To check this theory, just initialize the `orderIndex` member variable in the class constructor. Negative values you see are just uninitialized integer values of your `orderIndex` variables.

Comment: Incidentally, the garbage value you are seeing, when encoded as SINT32LE, is 0xbaadfood.

Comment: @vahancho ive updated my post to show my initial function which creates the list of objects. you may be able to point out an issue there if you see it.

Comment: Does the `MyObject` constructor set `orderIndex`?

Comment: @Botje no it's null by default. The function i later call sets it to a new value before i actually attempt to use it.

Comment: No such thing as 'by default'. If your constructor does not set it, `orderIndex` will contain stack garbage.

Comment: either way, i do set it to 0 and it doesn't help. Am I possibly not creating a list of objects correctly QList<MyObject> objects; should be QList<MyObject*> objects; or something?

Comment: @JokerMartini, please show the code (complete) that sets the order index. Where that `obj` comes from?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].  Also, does `MyObject` follow the [rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: @G.M. I've updated my question in hopes of you guys being able to better decipher and help me (newbie) out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your example code suffers from a number of problems but there's enough there to see (I think) what you're trying to do.

Firstly the code shown doesn't actually add any `MyObject` instances to the `QList<MyObject>` variable and -- based on some of the commented out code -- you've already hit the biggest problem: `QObject` is not copyable.  Since `MyObject` inherits from `QObject` that means that code such as the following simply won't compile...

```
QList<MyObject> objects;
MyObject obj("title");
objects.append(obj);
```

The call to `objects.append(...)` will generate an error message along the lines of...

> use of deleted function ‘MyObject::MyObject(const MyObject&)

To achieve what you want you'll need to store the `MyObject` instances by reference or pointer.  For example...

```
const QStringList names{"Kevin", "Amy", "Michelle", "John"};

QList<MyObject *> objects;
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    MyObject *obj = new MyObject(names[i]);
    obj->setIndex(i);
    objects.append(obj);
}

// Sort Alphabetically
std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
          [](const MyObject *a, const MyObject *b) -> bool
          {
              return a->getTitle() < b->getTitle();
          });

// Then Sort By Index
std::sort(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
          [](const MyObject *a, const MyObject *b) -> bool
          {
              return a->getIndex() < b->getIndex();
          });

// Print info
for (int i=0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    qDebug() << objects[i]->getIndex();
    qDebug() << objects[i]->getTitle();
}
```

Note that the above requires that *you* call `delete` on the various `MyObject` instances when you no longer need them -- the `QList` destructor wont do that for you.

Rather than using raw pointers you may want to look at the possibility of using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depending on your specific requirements.  That way you wont need to concern yourself to quite the same extent regarding memory management.